# Understanding "approval" workflow on List

Tags: list, 2013, workflow, publishing, content-approval

I am totally confused regarding approval workflow on List. I thought I had figured it out but looks like that's not the case.

I simply want to achieve the following.

1. I have a list named "Test"
2. This list is being published on home page
3. When ever a user adds new item in it or edits existing item, I want someone to approve it before it is visible on home page.

Now to do this I enabled OOB publishing workflow in list. But this workflow is totally useless because whether the item is "In Progress" or "Rejected", it always shows up on home page as soon as someone adds it in list.

So I removed this workflow and enabled that Content Approval workflow which you find in "Versioning Settings" of list. Now this one actually works like the way I want but it doesn't send email alert to approver so it is useless also.

So then I tried to use both of them i.e. Publishing workflow and Content approval workflow on list. But this is totally confusing because let's say in Content approval I "Reject" and item but in Publishing workflow I "Approve" that item which doesn't make any sense!!!

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue on a Calendar approval. The easy solution was to "filter" the list on Approval Status equal to APPROVED.